# How to type text on text fields and click on a button using AutoIt

Tags: autoit

I have a JNLP file (say Test.jnlp). I have opened that file using AutoIt. My code for opening Test.jnlp file:

```
$d = "D:\Ripon\"
$f = "Test.jnlp"
Run("cmd /c " & " """ & $d & $f & """ ", "", @SW_HIDE)
```

After opening .jnlp file a Login screen comes. My requirement is to type Username and Password -> Click Login button.
As I couldn't find the identity of elements (text fields, button) I failed to do that. Please help me.

[image]

Comment: WHAT exactly failed? Cant you enter something or doesn't the login work?

Comment: Actually I couldn't find out identity of text fields and button. I need id, name or something like that of elements (such as text fields, button)

Comment: Test.jnlp file can also be opened by this way: ShellExecute("D:\Ripon\Test.jnlp")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few types of GUI that don't give you ids for controls, almost all Java toolkits are an example of that.

There are several methods of automating them still:

1. Assuming the window is always the same size (which is often a pretty safe assumption to make) then AutoIt will allow you to click the window at a given position, or send text just to that window. For example in the above case you could try the following code:

   `ControlSend("Window Title", "", "", "MyUsername{TAB}MyPassword{ENTER}")`
2. Another solution is using accessibility features. If you google 'autoit java accessibility bridge' I'm sure you'll get some results like [this one](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/154203-java-accessibility-bridge-respond-to-upfront-unknown-message/). I've never tried this personally.
3. There is also a [java access bridge](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/87956-java-udf/) no idea how this works either, but other people have been using it for a while.

As a last resort, you have to mimic user mouse and keyboard actions. This really isn't the best solution but at least you can be very sure it will work.

Comment: Thanks Matt, for giving nice solution. I tried no. 1 and worked well. I shall also go for trying no. 2 & 3 to gather knowledge

Comment: Important is, that using the ID is OPTIONAL! You can use the ControlCommands without a given ID aswell!

Answer (score 1):

The following snippet of code should work:

```
Send("username")
Send("{TAB}")
Send("password")
Send("{ENTER}")
```